# How to clone HashMap with a set of classes in Java

Tags: hashmap, clone

```
HashMap<String, Set<Myclass>> mapNew = new HashMap<String, Set<Myclass>>();

for (Map.Entry<String, Set< Myclass >> entry : mapOrig.entrySet()) {
        mapNew.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().clone());  
    }
```

.clone() does not work here
I want to change an item in the new but leave the original unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this but it seems awkward. Is there a better way?

```
    for (Map.Entry<String, Set< Myclass >> entry : mapOrig.entrySet()) {
        Set<Myclass> objs = entry.getValue();
        Set<Myclass> objsCloned = new HashSet<Myclass>();
        for(Myclass obj : objs)
        {
            objsCloned.add(obj.clone());
        }

        mapNew.put(entry.getKey(), objsCloned);
     }
```

Comment: Yes this is awkward objsCloned is null and never get a proper instance of a Set so it can't works :)

Comment: I changed objsCloned to a proper init, how now?

Comment: i don't know how works map and set clone function, but i guess like this it's fine, as long you always use an hashet, it's a proper cloning.